# Set of combinations of numbers from another set, but also described as a named sequence?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I'm trying to put my program into a more mathematical model.

---

I have these parameters that are fairly easy to describe:

**Parameters**

**I'll put my sidenotes in quoteblocks.**

$V = \{1, 3, 5, 6\}$ - set of available digits

$V_n =$ value of $n$-th indexed element within set $V$

> So, $V_1 = 1$, $V_2 = 3$ ..

$j, k = 2, 5$ - upper and bottom range for combinations generation

> By "combinations generation" I mean that $C$ will hold all combinations for $V$ elements in quantity of 2 to 5 elements.

$X$ - a single combination of objects from set $V$ in form of a sequence

> A single sequence of numbers that holds a combination of $V's$, so for example: (1, 3, 3, 5) or (1, 1) or (1, 6, 5, 3, 5) and so on..

$S_p$ - sum of values of sequence p passed to it

> I want this to be kind of a function that returns a value. If p is a sequence and I pass any X to it, I want it to return the sum of it's values.
>   In other words - passing to it an X that's equal to (1, 3, 3, 1) should return 8

$C = \{X_j = (V_1, V_1), X_{j+1} =(V_1, V_2), ..,X_k = (V_4, V_4, V_4, V_4, V_4)\}$ - set of all combinations for sequences containing from $j$ to $k$ elements. Each element is an $X$

> I agree, this could be hard to comprehend and I could be the only person that knows what's written there - being the author of it, but that's what the whole post is asking about.
>   Here it is - $C$ is meant to hold every combination for 2, 3, 4 and 5 elements. Every said combination is an $X$, hence why "$X_1 = ..$". Every $X$ inside of $C$ is also a sequence of digits inside of set $V$, hence why "$X_1 = (V_1, V_1)$".
>   Now, I wanted to make sure that it's clear that there will be combinations for 2 up to 5 $V$ set elements, so I've described the first element $(V_1, V_1)$ the second element (to show the step) $(V_1, V_2)$ and the last element $(V_4,V_4,V_4,V_4,V_4)$

$C_n$ - set of $X's$, where $|X| = n$

---

Now, if the above parameters are properly defined

Will below properly set $a$ to '4', if $C_3$ = X which is a sequence = (1, 3)?:

$a = S_{C_3}$

Thank you in advance - I've only just started learning how to mathematically model my algorithms and problems, after years of being a programmer.

Comment: Amazingly incomprehensible.

Comment: @WilliamElliot I'm not surprised.

Comment: See my new answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let D be a set of digits.
D$^n$ is the set of sequences of digits from D with length n.

$C_{mn} = D^m \cup D^{m+1} \cup...\cup D^n$
is the set of all combinations with lengths from m through n.

Does that cover it all except for the sum of digits functions?

Comment: How does that describe them as being combinations with repetitions? I don't think I understand this entirely.

Comment: For example D$^3$ = { (x,y,z) : x,y,z in D } includes (3,1,5), (3,3,5), (1,1,1) and (5,3,5).

Comment: now I get it, or so I think.